# How to implement bcrypt in an angular6 project

Tags: angular, typescript, cryptography, bcrypt

Hi I am trying to hash a key using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)  npm package but it's throws me errors. Till now I have tried this code.

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export class LowLevelEncryption {

    encrypt(key: string){
        console.log(bcrypt);
         bcrypt.hash(key, 19, function(err, hash) {
           Store hash in your password DB.
         });
    }

}
```

It throw many error like this:-

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/ec2-user/environment/passcript/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
```

can please someone help me or anyone knows any other library.
Thanks

Comment: Angular applications execute in the browser. The library you're using is designed to be run in a NodeJS environment, on the server.

Comment: You could try the bcryptjs project on github - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try crypto-js, and use whatever strategy you need, something like :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import * as crypto from 'crypto-js';

    @Injectable()
    export class CryptoService {

    constructor() {
    }


   encrypt(key: any, privateKey: any) {
     const cryptkey = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(privateKey);
     const encrypted = crypto.AES.encrypt(key, cryptkey, {
      iv: crypto.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000'),
      mode: crypto.mode.ECB,
      padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7
   });
   return encrypted.toString();
  }


  decrypt(cryptedKey: any, privateKey: any) {
    const cryptoPrivateKey = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(privateKey);
    const encryptedKey = crypto.enc.Base64.parse(cryptedKey);
    const decrypted = crypto.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: encryptedKey}, cryptoPrivateKey, {
      iv: crypto.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000'),
      mode: crypto.mode.ECB,
      padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7
   });
   return decrypted.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
  }
}
```

Or even simpler : to encrypt

```
const encryptedPassword = crypto.AES.encrypt(value, 'password');
```

and decrypt

```
const bytes  = crypto.AES.decrypt(encryptedPassword, 'password');
const decryptedPassword = bytes.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
```

Hope this helps